# SQL table with multiple foriegn keys

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a table with multiple keys

```
 CREATE TABLE Wishlist (ID integer NOT NULL,  productname varchar(30) NOT NULL, price integer NOT NULL, email varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (productname) REFERENCES products (productname),
    FOREIGN KEY (price) REFERENCES products (price), 
    FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES products (email)
    );
```

> The error "a UNIQUE constraint does not exist on referenced columns *repeats code*" If i change it to:

```
CREATE TABLE Wishlist (ID integer UNIQUE NOT NULL,  productname varchar(30) NOT NULL, price integer NOT NULL, email varchar(30) NOT NULL, // rest same as above
```

> The error "a UNIQUE constraints already exists on the set of columns in statement *repeats code*" if i then remove the primary key, the first error message appears, any suggestions??

Comment: Can you share DDL of products table?

Comment: The table you are trying to create is horribly denormalized. Why do you want the productname in the Wishlist table? It should be a reference to the primary key of products, not the name. And the price and email columns just simply don't make any sense whatsoever. You need to read on normalization and build your table with that in mind.

Comment: same price can come multiple time

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary for the table to have multiple keys? I would suggest that you just make one foreign key which references any unique column in the product table (like the id), then you can just write the product id of the product that is in the wishlist into the product id columnn in the wishlist table. This will give the email and price too (from the product table) when you join together the two tables.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for your comments i took what you said into consideration and redesigned my database for the better

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys can only be configured on columns in the foreign table that are indexed.  Make sure the columns in the foreign tables have an indexed configured.  Typically, most foreign keys are configured to the tables PK but non-clustered index work also.